# Interpret Code - Non PHP Programmer

Tags: php

What is this code doing?

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't help but something tells me this is another homework :)

Comment: @fabrik: hopefully not, this code is not really secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is to upload a file in the destination directory. Is there anything else do you want to understand.

This will upload the file in the path you have in variable `$_REQUEST['folder']`

Answer (score 1):

It is basically uploading a file and echoing the target file's name.

There should also be something like an HTML form to send the file to this script.

Comment: Where is it uploading the file?

Comment: @Calvin Han: To the value of the variable `$_REQUEST['folder']`. This value should be send with the request. Do you also have some code like `<form> .. some code .. </form>`?

Comment: It's uploading the file to the document root - which is where the php file is and it is getting a folder name from the request.

Comment: @Calvin Han: Did I answer your question or do you need to know anything else?

Answer (score 1):

It accepts an user uploaded file, and puts it in your webroot in a folder, specified by the user. Then it outputs the path of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Storing files uploaded (possibly via HTML form) onto server.

Answer (score 0):

It's accepting a file posted by a HTML form and uploading it to a certain directory within a server. After that it's displaying the location of the file on screen (in the browser).